# I try to use "scoop" to install symfony-cli but every time I get the following error: Couldn't find manifest for 'symfony-cli'

Tags: symfony, scoop-installer

[Screenshot of the error obtained on Windows PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Taab3.png)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is still a bug in `scoop` https://jonathansoma.com/everything/setup/scoop-issues/

I have got the same error

```
Couldn't find manifest for <my_package>.
```

and the solution provided by this link worked for me. Just remove the bucket your package comes from and then add it back:

```
> scoop bucket rm main
> scoop bucket add main
> scoop install <my_package>

Installing <my_package> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try this:

```
scoop bucket add main
scoop install symfony-cli
```